# Read the content of file .ods

Tags: android, json, ods

I'm creating an application with android studio that analyze datas in a file on google drive (.ods).
I have already transformed this file .ods in json.
Now i need how to connect this file with the application.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community to help each other learn to program. We are not a code writing service.

Comment: Please read [help/on-topic] and [mcve] for tips to improve your question.

Comment: i dont have ideas how do this

Comment: Start with google. Something like "open json file android" will give you many hits.

Comment: Also read [ask].